# Recurrence results stored in list in Prolog

Tags: list, error-handling, prolog, recurrence, instantiation-error

I am trying to create a Prolog program for solving the recurrent equation:

> f(1)=2, f(2)=5, f(n)=f(n-1)+2*f(n-2)

I managed with the rec function below, but I have trouble when I want to store the result in the list (by function recList).
This is my implementation:

```
rec(1,2).
rec(2,5).
rec(X,N) :- X1 is X-1, X2 is X-2, rec(X1,N1), rec(X2,N2), N is N1+2*N2.

recList(0,[]).
recList(X,[N|L]) :- rec(X,N), X1 is X-1, recList(X1,L).
```

My implementation of recList works for calling it by the first value

```
?- recList(4,X).
```

->

```
X = [19, 9, 5, 2] .
```

but it doesn't when I call it by the second one if it is longer than two elements:

```
?- rekurList(X,[2]).
X = 1 .

?- rekurList(X,[5,2]).
X = 2 .

?- rekurList(X,[9,5,2]).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
ERROR: In:
ERROR:    [9] rec(_12587334,9)
ERROR:    [8] rekurList(_12587360,[9,5|...]) at /locaiton/rec.pl:6
ERROR:    [7] <user>
```

What is wrong, please?

Comment: it's same as you program fibonacci numbers, all you need is to store intermediate result, you can do that by adding one more statement at the end when you calculate result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The predicate `is/2` fails because `is/2` evaluates the right-hand structure as an arithmetic expression. If it is not a valid arithmetic expression or a number, `is/2` fails. So when you call

```
recList(X, [19, 9, 5, 2]).
```

you get `rec/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`. If you run the tracer (in SWISH, which is SWI on line: `trace, recList(X, [19, 9, 5, 2]).` In ECLiPSe you can use `tkeclipse Tools->Tracer`) you get something like:

```
Call:recList(_13806, [19, 9, 5, 2])
 Call:rec(_13806, 19)
 Call:_14048 is _13806+-1
 Exception:_14102 is _13806+-1
is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

To solve this problem you can use the library `clpfd` in this way (i wrote the solution using SWI):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

rec(1,2).
rec(2,5).
rec(X,N):- 
    X1 #> 0,
    X1 #= X-1, 
    rec(X1,N1),
    X2 #> 0,
    X2 #= X-2,  
    rec(X2,N2),
    N #= N1+2*N2, !. %notice the cut (!)

recList(0,[]):-!.
recList(X,[N|L]):- 
    rec(X,N), 
    X1 #= X-1, 
    recList(X1,L).
```

Query:

```
?- recList(X, [19, 9, 5, 2]).
X = 4.
false.

?- recList(4,L).
L = [19, 9, 5, 2]
false
```

Note that the cut `!` is needed because otherwise, after the first solution, if you click more, the computation will never end. Also `X1 #> 0` and `X2 #> 0` are needed because otherwise you get a `out of local stack` error.

Comment: Cool, thanks. And is it also possible without the library somehow?

Comment: I don't think is possible to do easily. Without `clpfd`, i think you should add some counters and instantiate the value of each counter before calling the predicate `rec/2` (which will need more arguments).